# Why does booting tmpfs overlayroot filesystem on read-only disk boot to emergency mode?

Tags: ubuntu, tmpfs

I enabled tmpfs overlayroot running following.

```
$ sudo sed -i 's/overlayroot=""/overlayroot="tmpfs"/g' /etc/overlayroot.conf
```

After rebooting, Ubuntu boots as read-only and everything works as expected and nothing is written to disk (confirmed using disk checksum).

Then, when I set disk to hardware read-only (a feature of datAshur PRO² USB flash drives), Ubuntu boots to emergency mode.

**UPDATE:** using `fsck.mode=skip` solves the issue but why do I have to skip filesystem check?

Why? What am I missing? Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Not sure if it is related but running `journalctl` reveals “fsck failed with exit status 6.” error.

Comment: By default systemd-fsck could still result in write because `The default` of fsck.repair= `is "preen"` because `will automatically repair problems that can be safely fixed`. Even if there's nothing to repair, the program (or the real fs-specific fsck program it calls) would probably "open" the partition it checks in read-write mode, which could still fail if it somehow detects that the device is read-only (e.g. if you see `RO` being `1` when you turn on the hardware read-only feature). See if `fsck.repair=no` helps. (Probably not though, because it really just `answer no to all questions`.

Comment: Thanks for helping out @TomYan. Would you recommend using `fsck.repair=no` rather than `fsck.mode=skip`? If so, why?

Comment: Well, if it helps, it might allow you to at least *know* that something is wrong with the fs, but as I edited my last comment, it probably won't help, so you might need to skip it anyway. (Btw I missed "in `lsblk` output" when I wrote "see `RO` being `1`".)

Comment: Looks like `fsck.repair=no` works… will run a complete integration test and report back here if something comes up. Thanks for the feedback @TomYan.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe fsck sets some "dirty" bit when it starts and clears it once it's done?